# URL route location affects React-router pushState

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How does one generally handles the « URL basepath » (or the location) when routing?

Mini example:

```
'localhost/allworkouts' + pushState('target') => 'localhost/target'  ## OK
'localhost/me/workouts' + pushState('target') => 'localhost/me/target'  ## NOT OK
```

Detailed example, closer to what I am trying to achieve.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="/allworkouts" component={AllWorkoutsList}/>

  <Route onEnter={requireLogin}>
    <Route path="/me/profile" component={Profile}/>
  </Route>
</Route>

class Profile extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        // a list of the user's workouts
      <Link to='workout/:workoutId1'> </Link> // or pushState
      <Link to='workout/:workoutId2'> </Link>
      <Link to='workout/:workoutId3'> </Link>
        // these will go to localhost:3000/me/workout/xxx-yyyy
    );
  }
}

class AllWorkoutsList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        // a List of all available workouts in the universe
      <Link to='workout/:workoutId5'> </Link> // or pushState
      <Link to='workout/:workoutId6'> </Link>
      <Link to='workout/:workoutId7'> </Link>
        // this will go to localhost:3000/workout/1354-878656
    );
  }
}
```

I am using one "indirection" (`me/`) to help understand the fact that the data under that route has to be authorized and all that stuff. But components under `me/` will route to `localhost:3000/me/workout/xxx-yyyy` which is an undesired behaviour. I'd like a bit more control over the URL basepath when I use `Link` or `pushState`.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using absolute paths like '/workout/xxx'?

Comment: It works. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks.